# Select gives different answers in versions 8 and 9

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the code below:

```
s = Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, InverseFunctions -> True];
Select[s[[All, 1, 2]], Element[#, Reals] &]
```

In MMA 8.0, I get

```
{-\[Pi], \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}
```

but in MMA 9.0, I get an empty set { }

Assuming the solution by MMA 8.0 is correct, can someone show me a work around for MMA 9.0?

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour in my machine, running both MMA 8 and MMA 9...

Comment: Why not using `Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, Reals, 
 InverseFunctions -> True]` so you don't need to filter afterwards ?

Answer (score 4):

If you do this:

```
s = Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2, x, Reals];
x /. FullSimplify[s, Element[C[1], Integers]]
```

Both versions will give you the same result:

```
{1/2 (Pi - 8 Pi C[1]), Pi (-1 + 4 C[1]), Pi + 4 Pi C[1], -(1/2) Pi (3 + 8 C[1])}
```

Answer (score 4):

As belisarius observed, the result in version 9 contains additional constants that enumerate a range of equivalent solutions for `x`. This causes `s` to no longer contain the expressions you're looking for with `Select`.

One way to eliminate the additional constants is to specify what you'e looking for in the `Solve` expression directly, as for example here:

```
s = Solve[(3 - Cos[4*x])*(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) == 2 && -Pi <= x <= Pi, x, 
  InverseFunctions -> True]

{{x -> -Pi}, {x -> Pi/2}, {x -> Pi}}
```

This works equally in versions 8 and 9.